# Is the line created by the minor axis of an ellipse concurrent to the lines running to the opposite vanishing point?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry

My questions needs more context than what can fit into the title so let me elaborate. In pretty much all the art textbooks I am reading on linear perspective they state that the correct way of placing an ellipse is to imagine the minor axis of an ellipse as an axel of a wheel running to the opposite vanishing point. Here are examples for the various types of perspective the textbooks mention.

One point perspective:

In one point perspective only one set of parallel lines of a cuboid are concurrent, the other two sets are parallel (one set parallel to the horizon, the other perpendicular to it). If we plot an ellipses inside a one-point square the minor axis' should all run vertical (to the non-concurrent vanishing point). We find that only ellipses whose major axis are perpendicular to the vanishing point (A`) have this property.

[image: One Point perspective]

Two point perspective:

In two point perspective two of the sets of parallel lines of a cuboid are concurrent (meeting at R3 & S3 in the image) and the other set are not concurrent (parallel). I tried placing an ellipse such that the perspective center points of the sides of the quadrilateral are the tangent points of the ellipse but the minor axis does not seem concurrent with the lines running to the opposite concurrence (vanishing point). It should be stated that the two quadrilateral and their concurrences are a mirror reflection of each other, but this is not always the case in two point perspective.

[image: Two point perspective]

If I adjust the size of the bounding quadrilateral I can make the minor axis concurrent with the lines running to the opposite vanishing point... but what if I want an ellipse placed inside a different sized quadrilateral?

[image: Two point additional]

Am I missing something in my plotting of ellipses or are the authors of these textbooks mistaken?

Comment: Here are some links to a few of the textbooks I have been reading: https://www.idsa.org/sites/default/files/2002_Randy%20Bartlett.pdf
http://userwww.sfsu.edu/trogu/420/reference/perspective/tutorials/ellipses.html
https://courses.byui.edu/art110_new/art110/week01/minor.html

Comment: As I said some hours ago, you should provide a link to the previous questions you have recently aske like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3821917), all of them about similar issues. It can help people of good _will_ not to reinvent the _wheel_ (you mention :)) in their answers...

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. Here are some related questions about placing ellipses inside of quadrilaterals.
[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3820517/how-to-find-the-placement-of-an-ellipse-inside-a-scalene-quadrilateral-where-4-p)

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3819249/how-do-i-find-where-the-major-axis-of-an-ellipse-is-when-it-is-placed-inside-a-q)

Comment: I don't know if you have a question about my "answer", but, addressing directly your question, I would like to say that on the mathematical point of view the notion of minor/major axes and foci are classified as "metric properties" and aren't in the scope of projective geometry which (in particular) doesn't preserve neither the lengths nor the ratio of lengths (but the cross-ratio). Therefore, nothing astonishing that you find such discrepancies...

Comment: Are you endorsing my discovery? I must admit I am not fluent in the language of mathematics. I am trying to learn to understand perspective drawing however.

Comment: Should I be using mat lab instead of Geogrbra to make these diagrams?

Comment: 1) "Are you endorsing my discovery": I must think a little more about that, but the argument I just gave distinguishing metric from projective properties is a reason that any "geometer" will approve ; I am going to transfer these sentences at the beginning of my answer. 2) "Should I be using Matlab" (or any language of this type like Python): I am so used to programming languages for doing sometimes purely esthetical rendering that my answer is yes. If you want, I can send you examples of esthetical/scientific drawings I have made precisely with Matlab.

Comment: Sure, I would like to see them. I already know Python so the learning curve may not be too hard and I want to make aesthetic work with it.

Comment: All right for sending some figures. Through e-mail ?

Comment: I will send you soon some figures at this e-mail address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely right; the authors of these textbooks are mistaken, and your diagrams show why.

I happen to have watched a fair number of instruction videos on perspective drawing, and to my frustration, I haven't yet found a single one that addresses this mistake, even from the most meticulous and formal instructors.

This is somewhat understandable. Broadly speaking, artists establish rules based on aesthetics, intuition, and approximation; whereas mathematicians remain skeptical without proof. These are two valid mindsets for two different fields, and your question belongs to the overlap of the two. The danger of an artist learning the technical craft of perspective is that they might use rules of thumb indiscriminately without fully understanding when they apply. The danger of a mathematician learning to draw is that they might break out a straightedge and compass without considering whether that will actually contribute to a successful composition. It would be nice to find a happy middle ground between these two camps, but ellipses turn out to be surprisingly complex. A perfect geometric construction exists, but just isn't worth it in the the context of a larger drawing, so it's natural to look for a simpler way.

Note that the rule actually does work for isometric drawings. In other words, if all parallel lines remain parallel (as opposed to converging to a vanishing point), then it holds. There are other cases where it holds, as you allude to in the comments. Most importantly, the rule will be reasonably close when the drawing is within the cone of vision. In contrast, in your first example, the leftmost circle is outside the cone of vision and therefore quite distorted.

In summary, the "rule" should be considered a good approximation most of the time, but the more distortion there is, the more likely you should abandon it and use your instincts (or a straightedge and compass).

Comment: A model of thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Minor/major axes, foci, etc. are "metric objects" that have a meaning in the framework of metric geometry, therefore are outside the scope of projective geometry which (in particular) doesn't preserve neither the lengths nor the ratio of lengths (but the cross-ratio). As a consequence, it is not astonishing that you find such discrepancies...

Besides, are you aware of the fact that a figure like your first figure can be easily obtained by programmation in a convenient language. For example, this figure:

[image]

*Fig. 1. Figure generated by a program written in Matlab (see bottom of this answer) The vanishing points are materialized by red dots. We see on this figure that we cannot infer anything on the orientations of the major/minor axis of the ellipses...*

Here is another figure, similar to the first one you have given with trapezoids instead of general quadrilaterals:

[image]

*Fig. 2: Figure obtained by changing $A$ into $[5+0.i,1+2i,0+0i]$ and changing denominator $(x+y+t)$ into $(y+t)$ in function $Z$. Only a single vanishing point at finite distance (the other one being at infinity).*

Explanation: everything is based on the common (and simple) expression of all projective transformations (in particular those giving a perspective):

$$X=\dfrac{ax+by+c}{gx+hy+k}, \ \  Y=\dfrac{dx+ey+f}{gx+hy+k}, \tag{1}$$

(please note the common denominator)
or equivalently:

$$Z=\dfrac{Ax+By+Ct}{gx+hy+kt}\tag{2}$$

$$\text{with} \ Z=X+iY, A=a+id, B=b+ie, C=c+if,$$

with $t=1$ for ordinary points and $t=0$ for points at infinity.

(using complex numbers for plane geometry is very handy).

Remark:

Here, in the plane with coordinates $(x,y)$, I have first described a chain of 6 tangent **circles** (+ circumscribed squares) to which I have applied a certain projective transform of the type given by (2).

Program:

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on
> A=[2+i,1+1i,0+0i]; % could be (almost) any set of comp. numbers
> Z=@(x,y,t)((A(1)*x+A(2)*y+A(3)*t)./(x+y+t)); % see formula (2)
> s=5; % shift
> a=0:0.01:2*pi; % parameter
> for k=1:4;
>    % ellipses as images of circles by "Z transform":
>    plot(Z(cos(a)+2*k,sin(a)+s,1)); 
>    % quadrilaterals as images of squares: 
>    plot(Z([-1,1,1,-1,-1]+2*k,[-1,-1,1,1,-1]+s,1)); 
> end;
> % vanishing points in the 2 directions, with $t=0$:
> plot(Z(1,0,0),'or','markerfacecolor','r'); 
> plot(Z(0,1,0),'or','markerfacecolor','r');
> ```

Comment: This is helpful to know that we can create these diagrams with Mat lab but the original questions was not quite answered. I have downloaded Matlab and am learning how to use it now.

Comment: I do see that in your example that the two points of concurrence include the principal axis of the ellipses. Is this a special case you have presented? Your example is that of a three point perspective as none of the sides of the quadrilateral are paralle. What about when the quadrilaterals are non-isosceles trapezoids as in two point perspective(my example demonstrates this)?

Comment: One can do it, with a small modification. See the second figure I just uploaded and its legend.

Comment: I think I have figured this out. The minor axis of an ellipse will go to the opposite vanishing point in two scenarios. The first is when the square the ellipses fit inside are isosceles trapezoids and the line that connects the two vanishing points is also a line of symmetry for the isosceles trapezoids. The second is a special case when the bounding trapezoid is scalene and it has a certain size. What the size is I am not sure however...

Comment: @Audus You bring there new elements. I will be looking at them.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a cylinder (prism with a circle as its base) rotated in space. I guess we all agree that the minor axes of the ellipses at the ends of that cylinder on the picture plane are parallel to the sides of the cylinder. Therefore they share a vanishing point. Now construct a rectangular prism such that the sides of the prism are tangent to the cylinders mantle surface. The base of this prism will be a square. The prism can arbitrarily be rotated around the axis of the cylinder but the tangent faces will still share the vanishing point with the cylinder and therefore with the minor axis of the ellipses created by the cylinder.

The art books on perspective drawing propably refer to either prisms with a square or a circle as their base. Therefore the above mentioned authors are correct for the implied boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Philipp. I think you will be surprised by the behavior of ellipses inscribed in quadrilaterals. I don't think your premise is correct that the minor axis of an ellipse will be parallel to the sides of the cylinder. It only will be for certain cases.

Comment: What makes you think that this premise is not correct? Let's say that premise was actually incorrect. Imagine a cylinder in space and rotate it around its central axis. If the minor axes of the ellipses at the ends of that cylinder were not aligned with that central axis, the cylinder would look different depending on its rotation. So what you are arguing for is that cylinders are not axisymmetrical...

Comment: Cylinders are axisymmetric. However, when you begin projecting points from the cylinder onto a plane, the image of the cylinder created on the plane is not always axisymmetric. Notice the second figure I provided in the question. You can see the minor axis of the ellipse inscribed in the quadrilateral is not parallel to any of the sides of the bounding quadrilateral. This bounding quadrilateral represents the cuboid, (or rectangular prism) that is tangent to the inscribed cylinder. It is not intuitive that this is the case but perhaps this is why so many textbooks on this subject are wrong.

Comment: Do you have an example of an image of a cylinder that is not axisymmetric?
You did not provide any indication about how the lines in your figures are constructed. For example the vertical lines that create the planes of the prism. Therefore I assumed you made one of the following mistakes constructing the ellipse:
1. Prism has a base that is not a square but an arbitrary rectangle.
2. Angle between the planes of the prism is not 90°.
3. The ellipse is not placed correctly in the square in perspective.